# Tomcat mariadb connection configuration

Tags: tomcat, mariadb, tomcat8.5

I am using CentOS as Operating System, Mariadb as Database Server, and apache tomcat 8.5.xx as a web Server.

the Code of the Resource in Server.xml is as the following:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/HasanDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxTotal="50" maxIdle="15" minIdle="5" initialSize="2" maxWaitMillis="10000"
              removeAbondend="true" removeAbondendTimeout="300"
              validationQuery="select 1" testWhileIdle="true" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000"
              username="hasan" password="hasanpass" driverClassName="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/HasanDB"/>
```

I tried to connect using normal MySQL Driver but I get Access denied error for user hasan. I and when I try to connect using mariadbdriver, I get the following error in the logfile:

```
    02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.751 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.771 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
 java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:982)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:244)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:997)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:630)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)

02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.773 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:630)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:999)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:982)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:244)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:997)
    ... 13 more

02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.773 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-443"]
02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.773 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-443"]
 java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:982)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:244)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:997)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:630)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)

02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.773 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:630)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:999)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:982)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:244)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:997)
    ... 13 more

02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.773 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.779 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.780 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 595 ms
02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.788 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = StamperDB Ignoring unknown property: value of "true" for "removeAbondend" property
02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.788 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = StamperDB Ignoring unknown property: value of "300" for "removeAbondendTimeout" property
02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.826 WARNING [main] org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup Unexpected exception resolving reference
 java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection refused (Connection refused))
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2303)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2043)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:596)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:275)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:94)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:839)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:827)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:661)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:161)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.connException(ExceptionMapper.java:79)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1040)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:490)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:144)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:90)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:257)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2313)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2299)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:398)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1032)
    ... 30 more

02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.827 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource Failed to register in JMX: [javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection refused (Connection refused))]
02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.861 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = StamperDB Ignoring unknown property: value of "true" for "removeAbondend" property
02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.861 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = StamperDB Ignoring unknown property: value of "300" for "removeAbondendTimeout" property
02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.861 WARNING [main] org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup Unexpected exception resolving reference
 java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection refused (Connection refused))
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2303)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2043)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:596)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:275)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:94)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:839)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:117)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:71)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:786)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:161)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.connException(ExceptionMapper.java:79)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1040)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:490)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:144)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:90)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:257)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2313)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2299)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:398)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1032)
    ... 34 more

02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.862 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans Exception processing Global JNDI Resources
 javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection refused (Connection refused))
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:856)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:117)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:71)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:786)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)

02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.862 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [stamping]
02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.862 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.20
02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.870 INFO [stamping-startStop-1] at.tilak.j2ee.realm.StampingRealm.getDigest CredentialHandler: ch class isclass org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler
02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.871 INFO [stamping-startStop-1] at.tilak.j2ee.realm.StampingRealm.getDigest MessageDigestCredentialHandler: ch digest isMD5
02-Oct-2017 11:25:30.899 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ss1.war]
02-Oct-2017 11:25:31.590 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
02-Oct-2017 11:25:32.080 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = StamperDB Ignoring unknown property: value of "true" for "removeAbondend" property
02-Oct-2017 11:25:32.080 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = StamperDB Ignoring unknown property: value of "300" for "removeAbondendTimeout" property
02-Oct-2017 11:25:32.147 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ss1.war] has finished in [1,247] ms
02-Oct-2017 11:25:32.148 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
02-Oct-2017 11:25:32.200 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
02-Oct-2017 11:25:32.201 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [53] ms
02-Oct-2017 11:25:32.201 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs]
02-Oct-2017 11:25:32.254 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
02-Oct-2017 11:25:32.254 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [53] ms
02-Oct-2017 11:25:32.254 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples]
02-Oct-2017 11:25:32.390 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
02-Oct-2017 11:25:32.412 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
02-Oct-2017 11:25:32.412 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
02-Oct-2017 11:25:32.415 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [161] ms
02-Oct-2017 11:25:32.415 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
02-Oct-2017 11:25:33.020 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
02-Oct-2017 11:25:33.023 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [608] ms
02-Oct-2017 11:25:33.023 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager]
02-Oct-2017 11:25:33.426 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
02-Oct-2017 11:25:33.427 INFO [srvaimstp1.tilak.cc-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [404] ms
02-Oct-2017 11:25:33.431 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
02-Oct-2017 11:25:33.481 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 2700 ms
```

I think that this is the main error: Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection refused (Connection refused)

Comment: Check the permissions on the"socket".

Comment: I have made a small Java application, and it could connect easily!!