# Tomcat webservice configuration

Tags: tomcat, ssl, configuration

I have made a webservice (XML-RPC) built on Tomcat 8.5.16
it makes digital signiture of the data sent to it and saves them in MySQL (or MariaDB).
It runns fine on windows (without security).
Now I want to deploy it on CentOS (with SSL security).
always makes errors addressed in: 
[Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602066/failed-to-initialize-end-point-associated-with-protocolhandler)
and:
[Tomcat mariadb connection configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522668/tomcat-mariadb-connection-configuration)

To understand the problem:

1. I have made a simple XML-RPC web service (summ of 2 nummbers) and it runns correctly.
2. I have made a java application that accesses the database and it runns correctly.

I couldnt define the problem of the main app. 
could you please help me?

Comment: ` java.net.SocketException: Permission denied` Ensure tomcat starts with a user with enough permissions. For example try with root user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like your tomcat cannot open network sockets due to permission problems. Could be firewall and / or SELINUX.

You are using CENTOS. Did you opened your firewall :

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Also try to turn of SELINUX security for a moment with

```
setenforce=0
```

When this changes are made, restart tomcat.

I also suggest you to create a virtual CentOS image and try there first.